# cucumber.runtime.java.ObjectFactoryLoader loadSingleObjectFactory

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, cucumber-jvm, picocontainer

While running my test runner class getting this:
cucumber.runtime.java.ObjectFactoryLoader loadSingleObjectFactory
INFO: Loading ObjectFactory via service loader: io.cucumber.picocontainer.PicoFactory

Comment: Hi Kumar, welcome to SO. Is this a WARNING, then please [edit] your question and __post the complete console output__. It might be related to cucumber [issue #1691](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1691)